# Como ler uma ID de uma DIV, e colocar em uma VAR?

Tags: javascript, html

Amigos,

Em minha pagina, com essa DIV listada abaixo, eu precisaria "ler" a id que esta na tag **< a id="memo-list-delete-6_2544_0" >**  ou seja o valor **"memo-list-delete-6_2544_0"** e colocar em uma variavel para usar mais tarde.. como fazer isso com JS ?

```
    <div id="memo-list-6">
        <i>Testo 00</i>
        <pre> Texto 01 </pre>
        <a id="memo-list-delete-6_2544_0" >
            <span class="UmaClasse">    </span>
        </a>
    </div>
```

tentei fazer:

```
var MinhaInfo = document.querySelectorAll('#memo-list-6 a').length;
```

mas ele so retorna um numero...

Comment: Tens mais que uma div onde precisas fazer isso?

Comment: sim sergio, chega perto das 1000 divs....

Comment: Ok, podes explicar mais sobre a tua lógicade código? Assim podes receber ainda mais dicas

Comment: Ola Sergio vou tentar, embora eu seja novato e tenha dificuldades em me expressar! Também quero lembrar que a questão já foi resolvida, então a partir desse ponto fica valendo o estudo! Eu precisava de algo rapido e pratico apenas para a exibicao da pagina. Neste site.. o cliente pode subir uma imagem para ser analizada, e fazer anotacoes , e o tecnico pode fazer anotacoes tambem. E depois o revisor.. e assim por diante..  ate o trabalho final, em certo ponto existem muitas divs com as anotacoes, cores etc...mas todas com id com a mesma sequencia "memo-list-xxx"

Comment: acontece que alguns  nao precisam ver as notas de outros, o que se resolve com um display; none;...   acontece que fazer u for/if deixava tudo lento. mas esse codigo abaixo ficou quase instantaneo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acredito que seria isso Roberval:

```
var MinhaInfo = $('#memo-list-6 a').attr('id');
```

E só como uma dica de boa prática, tente sempre utilizar o padrao de nomeclatura para variaveis em qualquer linguagem que você estiver programando. [Para javascript o padrão é o camelCase](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_conventions.asp).

Basicamente o camelCase diz que a primeira palavra da variavel sempre comecará com uma letra minuscula e a partir dai as palavras comecam com letras maiusculas. Exemplos:

```
var minhaInfo = 1;
var minhaVariavelManeira = 2;
var variavelPadraoCamelCase = 3;
var camelCase = 4;
```

Comment: Nossa valeu muitooo!  E Ja vou adotar aquelas dicas ali! Brigadao!